# Why does multithreading operations on a single numpy array improve performance?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

In short, my question is **shouldn't Python block multiple accesses to the same memory?**

##### In detail

Say I want to do some computations on one hundred numpy arrays. My data is stored as a contiguous `np.ndarray` with shape `(100, 1000, 1000)`. As per the code below,  I iterate through the data and call `multiply` for each block of size `(1000, 1000)`. To avoid unnecessary copying, the results are stored in an already initialized array.

```py
import numpy as np
import time

data = np.random.random((100, 1000, 1000))
result = np.zeros((100, 1000, 1000))

def multiply(source, dest):
    """Dummy calculation"""
    np.divide(source, 1.5, out=dest)

start = time.time()

# Call multiply on each subarray
for i in range(100):
    multiply(data[i], result[i])

print(f"For loop exec time {time.time() - start:.3f} seconds")
```

This, on my system, yields

```
>>> For loop exec time 0.381 seconds
```

##### With concurrency

Next, I rewrite the code above to utilize tools from `concurrent.futures`. I launch a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, and submit ten asynchronous calls to `multiply` at a time, waiting them to finish, and ultimately processing all of my data.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait

threaded_result = np.zeros((100, 1000, 1000))

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()

start = time.time()

for i in range(10):
    futures = {
        executor.submit(
            multiply, # callable
            data[i*10 + j],
            threaded_result[i*10 + j],
        ) for j in range(10)
    }
    wait(futures)

print(f"Threaded exec time {time.time() - start:.3f} seconds")

executor.shutdown()

print(f"Both equal: {np.allclose(result, threaded_result)}") # Sanity check
```

Outputting

```
>>> Threaded exec time 0.079 seconds
>>> Both equal: True
```

##### What I don't understand

I tried this just out of curiosity, expecting both approaches to run in an approximately equal amount of time and was surprised by the result. My understanding of numpy internals is, that when passing `array[index]` to a function, you are actually passing the entire `array`, but with an offset and size specific to the subarray.

So when the underlying implementation of `np.multiply` receives subarrays `data[i]` and `result[i]`, wouldn't CPython stop all other threads from operating on the *entire* `data` and `result`?

Is the speedup because of some technical detail (i.e. multiple threads can *read* `data`, calculate the result into a buffer, and then wait their turn to write it into `result`), or is my understanding of the underlying mechanics **fundamentally** wrong? Any insight or references are much appreciated!

Comment: No.  Remember that `numpy` is written in C (and Fortran), and does not have to follow Python's rules at a high level.  It has its own internal mechanisms for protection, and they operate at a finer grain.

Comment: Per Tim Roberts comment, NumPy was created by Travis Oliphant largely in C, and has a very different philosophy and performance from Guido van Rossum's built-in Python.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I am aware that `numpy` is written mostly in C. However, aren't the functions bound through a CPython extension - wouldn't it stop the passed objects (arrays) to be used by other threads until they are dereferenced? Or does numpy somehow keep track of all queued memory writes under the hood.

I guess what I'm really getting at, is my code thread-safe? For example, if I change the strides of `result` midway through the concurrent loop - will it result in data races or will `numpy` handle everything for me.

Comment: It doesn't look like you would be writing to the same parts of the buffer, no? But I do not think numpy guarantees thread safety in cases like these

Comment: So, when you are executing a ufunc, numpy releases the GIL, so the other threads can take control of the python interpreter while the ufunc is doing work. I have no idea how this works with `out` parameters for writes, though, but it is the responsibility of numpy, and the Python interpreter is not able to give you guarantees.

Comment: yes, there are numerous 'NOGIL' macro blocks in the `numpy` c code.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, this actually answers my question, thank you! I had, for whatever reason, incorrectly thought that objects passed to a C extension are not allowed to be used by other threads until the function finishes, regardless of GIL. Now my benchmark makes sense.

Comment: As for not operating in same parts of the buffer - technically yes, but writing inherently unsafe code and making it work with some specific, correct parameters doesn't feel like a particularly good design choice.